# Need Proof of LCM inequality

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Let $x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n$ be positive integers. Prove that
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\text{lcm}(x_i,x_{i+1})}<1, $$
where $\text{lcm}(x,y)$ is the least common multiple of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $xy = \text{gcd}(x,y)\text{lcm}(x,y)$ and $\text{gcd}(x,y)$ divides $y-x$(thus less than or equal to $y-x$ when $y>x$), we have

$$\dfrac{1}{\text{lcm}(x_i, x_{i+1})} = \dfrac{\text{gcd}(x_i, x_{i+1})}{x_ix_{i+1}}\leq \dfrac{x_{i+1}-x_{i}}{x_ix_{i+1}} = \dfrac{1}{x_i} -\dfrac{1}{x_{i+1}}$$

where $\text{gcd}(x,y)$ is the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite understand why gcd(x,y)<y-x when y>x. For instance if y=4 and x=2 then gcd=2 and 2=4-2!

Comment: @chenh. By "less than" I actually mean $\leq$, I've edited to avoid confusion