# Inequalities involving the greatest common divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, gcd-and-lcm, functional-inequalities

**Question**

> What are some inequalities involving the greatest common divisor (GCD) function?

**Typical Answer**

$$\gcd(a,bc) \leq \gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,c)$$

**My Attempt**

I tried checking the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties), but the properties listed there for the greatest common divisor (GCD) function are all in the form of equations.

> > **Can you recommend an online resource/textbook/reference that lists properties for the GCD function in the form of inequalities?**

Comment: I learned about that **Typical Answer** via [FredH](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/82711)'s comment to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122247/28816).

Comment: I just found this [Wolfram link](http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/GCD/29/), which lists two inequalities involving the GCD, LCM and the product of the arguments.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322680/gcd-inequality-with-products-and-exponents and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023288/need-proof-of-lcm-inequality and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871278/number-theory-problem-fractions-and-gcd-please-help and Theorem 5.1 in https://books.google.com.au/books?id=3iHPwAS7F2AC&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=gcd+inequalities&source=bl&ots=v4u7UDw26T&sig=ACfU3U1Z66RYGIxbWYFn7eIC3U7McesIyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT-_rRsOPgAhUJVH0KHX3uCOgQ6AEwCnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=gcd%20inequalities&f=false

Comment: Thanks Gerry for providing those links!  Do you happen to know the source for the **Typical Answer** mentioned in my post?

Comment: The example is true by LSH *divides* RHS $= (a\color{#c00}{(a,b,c)},bc),\,$ i.s. $\,(a,bc)\mid a\color{#c00}d,bc\, \Rightarrow\, (a,bc)\mid (a\color{#c00}d,bc)$ $\qquad$